# SQL Report Builder: Return only date for available parameter values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I have a SQL Server report which prompts for a import date. Later I pass this date to a procedure to get the data (`dbo.spGetData`). My procedure to get the available import dates looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spGetImportDates
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, i.ImportDate) ImportDate
    FROM dbo.Import i
    ORDER BY i.ImportDate DESC
END
```

In the report I've added this SP as a new dataset and selected it as "Available Values" for the `Date/Time` parameter `@importDate` to get a dropdown. So far, so good. The problem is that the time is also included in the result set when I leave it like this:

```
+---------------------+
| ImportDate          |
+---------------------+
| 29.03.2017 00:00:00 |
| 25.03.2017 00:00:00 |
| ...                 |
+---------------------+
```

I couldn't find any option to change the format of the parameter prompt. I even tried to use the `SELECT` query directly in the query designer of the dataset but I get the same results.

Do I really have to use it as text parameter and then reconvert it to `DATE` in the procedure `dbo.spGetData` or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the ImportDate column in the stored procedure as DATE datatype.
Go to your dataset in SSRS and click on 'Fields'.
Add a new calculated field, name it ImportDateLabel and set it as the following expression:

```
=Format(Fields!ImportDate.Value,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Now go to your Paramater, click on 'Available values' and change the 'Label field' to reference the new ImportDateLabel field. Leave the 'Value field' pointing to the ImportDate field.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for :) btw I had to use `MM` instead of `mm` for the month.

Comment: Glad I helped. It's always a good idea to leave any formatting to the presentational layer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spGetImportDates
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATE, i.ImportDate) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS ImportDate
    FROM dbo.Import i
    ORDER BY i.ImportDate DESC
END
```

You can get only the first 10 characters and then convert it to varchar

Comment: Is there really no option to change the output format of the values in SQL Server Report Builder? When I do it like this I have to reconvert it to `DATE` type in my `spGetData` procedure.